# Flip a child element of a grid view to show another view

Tags: android

the target is to flip the element of the grid view to show another view. For example a gridview consists of pics and on click of the pic it has to rotate and has to show anotehr view consisting the detials of the person in the pic. I was trying ViewFlipper and objectAnimator but that doesnt seem to work and throwing an error (Unknown animation name objectAnimator). I will be needing a native implementation(without the use of libraries) in order make the code less bloated

Answer (score 0):

http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2013/05/transition-view-pager.html

use this example and add it in grid each grid .

Hope this helps ...